# while clause looping in R

Tags: r

I need help on the following code

I tried to generate a random series using while clause and met the following problem

When run codes as below

```
m1=0.82
set=rep(1, 1000)

while(mean(set)!=m1){
 k=sample(1:1000,1)
 if(set[k]!=0){set[k]=0}

 }
```

every thing is fine, however the loop can end if I change ml as as below

```
 m1=1-0.18
set=rep(1, 1000)

while(mean(set)!=m1){
 k=sample(1:1000,1)
if(set[k]!=0){set[k]=0}

}
```

just change from ml=0.82 to ml=1-0.18, R can't stop looping.

Comment: You've stumbled into a precision error, an R-FAQ. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/903061).

Comment: Run `0.82 == 1 - .18`. The fix is to set a tolerance, change your while condition to `abs(mean(set) - m1) < 1e-10`, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got stuck the whole morning

Comment: It's super confusing the first time you see it! (And worth pointing out that this is a general problem for programming, not R-specific at all.)